# Extracting lib from yocto build

Tags: yocto, sqlcipher, bitbake, openembedded

I have a yocto build setup for a NXP dev-board. I can build images just fine and I thought this would be a simple way to cross compile a static library that I need for another project.

I added  a recipe for the package, sqlcipher, and added `sqlcipher-staticdev` to `IMAGE_INSTALL` in `local.conf`.

This leads to me building sqlcipher just fine but I'm only getting dynamic libraries. I want to have a static library but even though I set DISABLE_STATIC = "" in the recipe I get nothing.

It has not been as easy as I first thought but is there a way to do this kind of thing?
Is there something else that needs to be done to build a static lib?

Comment: Are you sure you've rebuilt this package and rootfs? Try bitbake sqlcipher-staticdev -c cleanall, bitbake <your image> -C rootfs

Answer (score 0):

DISABLE_STATIC is appended to EXTRA_OECONF. Please check whether sqlcipher uses autotools to configure and whether has '--enable/disable-static' configure option.

Comment: I have manually added --enable-static=yes to EXTRA_OECONF. Could that be overridden by autotools class?

Comment: You could run `bitbake -e sqlcipher` to check the value of EXTRA_OECONF. What I mean is  to check source code of sqlcipher to make sure it uses autotools and accept configure option '--enable-static'. If it uses other configure/build tools such as cmake, you need to figure out what controls static library build.

Comment: You could run 'bitbake -e sqlcipher' to check the value of EXTRA_OECONF. What I mean is  to check source code of sqlcipher to make sure it uses autotools and accept configure option '--enable-static'. If it uses other configure/build tools such as cmake, you need to figure out what controls static library build.